# Flask package conflict - two different packages required two different version of importlib-metadata version

Tags: python

I've made a flask application and used virtualenv too
But after running `pip install -t lib -r requirements.txt`

it showing this error -

```
 The user requested importlib-metadata
    markdown 3.3.7 depends on importlib-metadata>=4.4; python_version < "3.10"
    spleeter 2.3.1 depends on importlib-metadata<4.0.0 and >=3.0.0; python_version < "3.8"
```

My current importlib-metadata version is 4.4 and python version is 3.6

I don't know how to use two different version of packages when the other two dependencies require two different specific version of same package.

Comment: remove versions from requirement.txt and keep package name and then install again with new packages

Comment: Thanks I remove the spleeter from requirements.txt and run it again and it worked. cheers..

Comment: added the comment as answer so it can be helpful in future to others

Answer (score 0):

It happens when you have conflict in the dependencies of your libs.

Looks like you are already using the most recent version of spleeter, and it forces you to have importlib-metadata < 4.0.0.

In this case, I suggest that you try to find a version of markdown that accepts importlib-metadata < 4.0.0 so you can install both together.

Usually if you simply remove the version from requirements.txt it will try to install the lib version that doesn't have the conflict, but I had situations in which it didn't work.

If for some reason remove the version doesn't work, you will need to manually find a version of markdown that doesn't conflict with spleeter.

Answer (score 0):

just remove the version from your requirement.txt file and keep package name. then install the packages in your virtual environment and it will work, to make requirement.txt file with version do `pip freeze`

ie convert this `requirement.txt`

```
package1=1.1.1
package2=1.2.3
package3=1.2.3
package4=3.1.1
```

to

```
package1
package2
package3
package4
```

now, install all  the packages agian from this `requirement.txt` file using command

```
python -m pip install -r requirement.txt
```

it will install all packages correctly.

To save the update  package version in `requirement.txt` file , run command

```
python -m pip freeze > requirement.txt
```